# Truncate table & insert ignore result in a #1062 - Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' error

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I have a very strange thing happening, this is my query:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `cms_clients`;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `cms_clients` (`id`,`col1`,`col2`,`col3`) VALUES
(4,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(5,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(6,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(7,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(8,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

The only primary key I have is `id`, and even though I have a `truncate` and `insert ignore` in the query it still results in the error:
`#1062 - Duplicate entry '4' for key 'PRIMARY' error` but when it previews that error and I view the table I can see that the rows `4` & `5` are already inserted, so the row `6` triggered the error; when I manually delete the rows `4` and `5` and run the query again I get the same error but on a different row: `#1062 - Duplicate entry '6' for key 'PRIMARY'` and same the previous one when I view the table I can see that the rows `4`,`5`,`6` and `7` are inserted so I believe that the row `8` is triggering the error.

This is the table's schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `cms_clients` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `col1` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `col2` varchar(180) NOT NULL,
 `col3` varchar(180) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Am I doing anything wrong or is my mysql starting to act a bit strange?

**EDIT**
I just tried it on another computer and it's working fine, I think the issue is in my mysql not the query.

Comment: What's the _exact_ version of your MySQL server ?

Comment: Are there any triggers on that table?

Comment: @angelcool.net 5.6.24

Comment: I tried your queries in MariaDB 5.5.40 without any issues, they worked fine.  Try changing the engine to InnoDB.